# executeShellCommand doesn't work and doesn't return error for telnet command

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Steps to have a fake GPS on a real device:

1. Install [MockGeoFix](https://github.com/luv/mockgeofix) and click "start"
2. When I open a terminal on my Mac and type:

   ```
    telnet 192.168.0.23 5554
    geo fix 5.1218252 52.0930999
   ```

This works.

But when I do this programmatically:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    try {
        String response = device.executeShellCommand("telnet 192.168.0.23 5554");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The app crashes immediately without even giving an error message.      minSdkVersion has been set to 21.

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat logs?

Answer (score 1):

You `telnet` command is in your local computer (Mac), not on your device.
When you invoke `executeShellCommand()` is to run commands available on your device not your computer.